# Does anybody have a Tinnitus?

Tags: health

Sine three months I have a soft (but annoying) Tinnitus on both ears. So far the doctor has checked my ears,  my head via a CT, xray'ed my backbone and so on and so on.
Since three months is a long time to live with this thing, I start to wonder if it will ever disappear again or if I have to get used to it.

So after this long intruduction comes the actual question :) :

Do any of you have a Tinnitus or something similar? Do you think, that it is a big problem if you want to work in sound?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a clear A major beeeep tone, on my right ear, since 2000.
First year or so, I was freaking out. The more I was thinking about it, the worse it got.
Especially when trying to go to sleep, was hard. The quiet nights made it really loud.
Through the years I have learned to live with it. My mind almost filters it out now, when I going to bed. 
Still, when coming home from a situation with lots of people etc. its there, reminding me to cover my ears.
Im wearing earplugs (those yellow thingies) when I listen to loud music, or record loud sources, and have not had any audio work related problems because of the T.

Quit smoking, drinking alc. and coffee, and do alot of exercise.This will help you alot! Trying not to think too much about it, will too!

I did this, and I have got my hands full, with 2 children now. I dont have trouble falling a sleep at night anymore :D

Sorry to hear about your tinnitus. It sucks, but hang in there. You can work around it!

Best wishes,

Mikkel

Answer (score 1):

I am lucky, in that I don't have tinnitus, but I could easily have had.  I started out in live sound and tinnitus was common amongst live sound engineers, especially monitor engineers.  Now it is acceptable to mix whilst wearing earplugs, but back then, late 80s early 90s it definitely was not acceptable.

We all of us have some form of hearing damage, even if we have been careful, it is called Presbycusis. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMH0002040/  It is definitely possible to work with some form of hearing damage, the important thing is to understand how it affects your work and adjust your work accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It bring's back an optimistic smile on my face again ;)